# good resources for learning Orca

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, configuration

have downloaded Orca to edit an MSI file. I want to remove some banner text during the installation. I have managed to do this to the MSI and saved it with the MSI. However am having problems in saving a template and then applying that to subsequent installers. Have looked at the help file for Orca and am basically lost on how to do this.
Can anyone suggest how I can make changes to Orca and save these changes and then apply them to subsequent MSI's which are just updates to the original MSI?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these [MSI interop tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/izfree/) to automate these changes - i.e. you decide (using ORCA) what and how you want changed, and then write a simple program to apply them to whatever installer you want.

Pretty good stuff.